# skype: error while loading shared libraries: libXss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: 64-bit, skype, 11.10, shared-library

I am using ubuntu 11.10 64bit,
skype was working however after running `sudo apt-get autoremove` skype is throwing

> skype: error while loading shared libraries: libXss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a library file. The program `apt-file` can be used to find which package provides a certain file. (`dpkg -S` does this too, but does not work for packages which are not installed)

`apt-file search libXss.so` yields:

```
ia32-libs: /usr/lib32/libXss.so
ia32-libs: /usr/lib32/libXss.so.1
ia32-libs: /usr/lib32/libXss.so.1.0.0
libxss-dev: /usr/lib/libXss.so
libxss1: /usr/lib/libXss.so.1
libxss1: /usr/lib/libXss.so.1.0.0
libxss1-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/libXss.so.1.0.0
```

You need to install the `libxss1` package for that library. If you're running the 32-bit version of Skype, `ia32-libs` needs to be installed instead of `libxss1`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Skype fails to find 'libsqlite3.so.0'. apt-file reports this is provided by libsqlite3-0 or libsqlite3-0.dbg. "apt-get install libsqlite3-0" reports it's already installed. "sudo ldconfig" does nothing. Skype still fails.

Comment: @JonathanHartley Try `sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-0:i386` instead as Skype is a 32-bit package.

Answer (score 15):

worked for me:

```
echo foreign-architecture i386 | sudo tee /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch
sudo apt-get install libxss1:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386
sudo apt-get install libqtgui4:i386
```

got from: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ia32-libs/+bug/830440

Comment: This worked for me although I had to run sudo apt-get -f install after the first line and get skype 32-bit from the Skype web-page.

Answer (score 5):

#### For later 64 bit Ubuntu versions

```
$ locate libXss.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1.0.0
$ dpkg -S libXss.so.1
libxss1:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1.0.0
libxss1:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1
```

So you have to install a 32 bit version of `libxss1` library file (ie,`libxss1:i386`) because there isn't a 64 bit version of skype. 32 bit Skype must need a 32 bit library file. So installing 32 bit version of `libxss1` package will solves your problem.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get install libxss1:i386
```