# skype: error while loading shared libraries: libXv.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: skype

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and have tried the suggestions in the following post: [skype: error while loading shared libraries: libXss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59703/skype-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libxss-so-1-cannot-open-shared-obj) and still get the same error

Comment: ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXv.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Jan 21 10:44 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXv.so.1 -> libXv.so.1.0.0

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstall libxv1:amd64 did not help. I get the same error.

Answer (score 9):

Locating the file,

```
$ locate /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXv.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXv.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXv.so.1.0.0
```

Finding the package which provides the above files,

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXv.so.1
libxv1:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXv.so.1
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXv.so.1.0.0
libxv1:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXv.so.1.0.0
```

So, you have to install `libxv1:i386` package. Because skype is available only for 32 bit version so it needs only a 32 bit version of library files not 64 bit version.

```
sudo apt-get install libxv1:i386
```

And don't forget to add i386 architecture before running the above command on 64 bit systems.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Comment: libxv1 is already installed

Comment: post the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep libxv1`

Comment: libxv1:amd64   install

Comment: post the output of `ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXv.so.1`

Comment: if it shows no such file or directory error then reinstall the `libxv1` package,`sudo apt-get install --reinstall libxv1:amd64`

Comment: skype: error while loading shared libraries: libXv.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: for me "sudo apt-get install libxv1:i386" worked. Even if you use a dynamic distribution of skype it seems that skype downloaded is still a 32 bit version of i386 arch. Hence this command works instead of the one suggested by Avinash.

Comment: to me none of the solutions proposed (on DEBIAN 8) worked. same error